# How to send data to view on send email in Laravel

Tags: laravel

i try this but it show Undefinded data

```
public function forgotPassword(Request $req){
    $token = rand();

    $data = $token;
    Mail::to($req->email)->send(new sendPass($data));
}
```

Comment: Please provide the whole error message you get, also please provide the code for the sendPass class

Comment: Can you put the code in for sendPass class

Answer (score 0):

First up, that code is a little bit inefficient. Why write :

```
$token = rand();
$data = $token;
Mail::to($req->email)->send(new sendPass($data));
```

when you could just write :

```
Mail::to($req->email)->send(new sendPass(rand()));
```

The issue is almost certainly because you've not declared $data in your SendPass class as a private variable :

```
class SendPass extends Mailable { 

    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $data;

    public function __construct(string $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $data = $this->$data;
        ... rest of your code goes here.
    }
```